# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^j}{j^s}\left(1-\frac{1}{j}\right)^n=\eta(s)-\eta(s-1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to show that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^j}{j^s}\left(1-\frac{1}{j}\right)^n=\eta(s)-\eta(s-1)$$

where $\eta$ is [eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function)

I did binomial transform but it is too difficult to proceed.

Comment: Note that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^j}{j^s}\left(1-\frac{1}{j}\right)^n=\sum_{j=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{(-1)^j}{j^s}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{1}{j}\right)^n\right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We define
$$\epsilon(s)=\sum_{j\ge2}\frac{(-1)^j}{j^s}\sum_{n\ge1}\left(1-\frac1j\right)^n.$$
So 
$$\epsilon(s)=\sum_{j\ge2}\frac{(-1)^j}{j^s}\cdot\frac{1-1/j}{1-(1-1/j)}=\sum_{j\ge2}\frac{(-1)^j}{j^s}(j-1).$$
You can take it from here, right?

Comment: No one explains why it is valid to change the order of summation (including the case $\Re s\in(1,2]$; it is easy but not entirely trivial).